# ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence in pandas and plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, runtime-error

When I run this code I keep getting -
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence.
And I couldn't find a way to solve it.

```
athlete_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset = {'Name','region'})
x=[]
name=[]
famous_sports = ['Basketball', 'Judo', 'Football', 'Athletics',
   'Swimming', 'Badminton', 'Sailing', 'Gymnastics', 'Handball', 'Weightlifting', 
   'Wrestling','Water Polo', 'Hockey', 'Rowing', 'Fencing',
   'Shooting', 'Boxing', 'Taekwondo', 'Cycling', 'Diving', 'Canoeing',
   'Tennis',  'Golf', 'Softball', 'Archery',
   'Volleyball',  'Table Tennis', 'Baseball',
   'Rhythmic Gymnastics', 'Trampolining',
   'Beach Volleyball', 'Triathlon', 'Rugby', 'Polo',
   'Cricket', 'Ice Hockey', 'Racquets', 'Motorboating', 'Croquet',
   'Figure Skating','Aeronautics']
for sport in famous_sports:
    temp = athlete_df[athlete_df['Sport']==sport]
    x.append(temp[temp['Medal']=='Gold']['Age'].dropna())
    name.append(sport)

fig = ff.create_distplot(x,name,show_hist=False,show_rug=False)
fig.show()


ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_2904/4081208800.py in <module>
----> 1 fig = 
ff.create_distplot(x,name,show_hist=False,show_rug=False)
      2 fig.show()

D:\Aanaconda Distribution\lib\site- 
packages\plotly\figure_factory\_distplot.py in 
create_distplot(hist_data, group_labels, bin_size, curve_type, 
colors, rug_text, histnorm, show_hist, show_curve, show_rug)
    216             ).make_normal()
    217         else:
--> 218             curve = _Distplot(
    219                 hist_data,
    220                 histnorm,

D:\Aanaconda Distribution\lib\site-
```

packages\plotly\figure_factory_distplot.py in **init**(self,
hist_data, histnorm, group_labels, bin_size, curve_type, colors,
rug_text, show_hist, show_curve)
316
317         for trace in self.hist_data:
--> 318             self.start.append(min(trace) * 1.0)
319             self.end.append(max(trace) * 1.0)
320

```
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

Comment: You are not calling `min`.  Where do you get that error?  Are you checking that `name` is not empty before you try to plot?

Comment: Yes I checked that, both x and name are non-empty before plotting.

Comment: Pls provide the data for x and name (dummy/sample) which will produce the error

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tudh7FNMnM9Mj-lNCayskjPRcZnK5rKp?usp=sharing 
All the data is in given link along with ipynb file

Answer (score 0):

You can append values only if not empty Series - it means if exist Gold medal with non missing values in `Age` for sport from list:

```
for sport in famous_sports:
    mask = (athlete_df['Sport']==sport) & (athlete_df['Medal']=='Gold') & df['Age'].notna()
    temp = athlete_df.loc[mask, 'Age']
    if not temp.empty:
        x.append(temp)
        name.append(sport)
```

Your solution:

```
for sport in famous_sports:
    temp = athlete_df[athlete_df['Sport']==sport]
    x.append(temp.loc[temp['Medal']=='Gold', 'Age'].dropna())
    name.append(sport)
```